# Dropdown first option value not functional

Tags: php, jquery, location, html-select

I have a problem whit my dropdown list,

I need to change location page when option selected using value option attribute, but the first option element not functional,
This is the html code:

```
<form>
                    <select class='language-select'   name='URL' id='URL'>

                        <option value="index.php?lan=EN" selected> English</option>
                        <option value="index.php?lan=FR">Français</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
```

and this is the Js function:

```
$('#URL').on('change', function(event){ 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    var $this = $(this);
                    window.location.href = $(this).val();
                    alert($(this).val());
                });
```

also there an error ' uncaught exception: out of memory'

One thing, when i add an empty option element it works well, i can toggle bettwen two links:  index.php?lan=FR and /index.php?lan=EN

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html marks the first `option` as `selected` no matter what.  So, for example, when the French page is loaded, your dropdown still says "English".  Instead, what you need to do is detect on page load which option should be selected.  You can use a function like this:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

And your markup would be:

```
<form>
     <select class='language-select'   name='URL' id='URL'>
          <option id="EN" value="index.php?lan=EN"> English</option>
          <option id="FR" value="index.php?lan=FR">Français</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Finally, in your jQuery on ready function, you would have:

```
$(function() {
    var lan = GetURLParameter('lan');
    $('#' + lan).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Hope it helps!